# Codeigniter Controller rendering blank on SERVER

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project. These are the symptoms of my problem.

1. My controller is displaying blank page.(name : signup)
2. My other controllers are running well with no problems.
3. The signup controller is runnign good on my localhost but giving problem on server.
4. I haven't used andy modified .htaccess file.
5. Sometimes the page also shows 'Internal Server Error'

Things I did to rectify

1. I changed my `$config['base_url']` = my web address
2. I reuploaded all the files to server

I am not able to point out the problem.

This is my controller code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Signup extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent:: __construct();
            $this->load->model('users_model','',TRUE);
        }
        public function index()
        {
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $data['title'] = "User Signup";
            $data['type'] = "admin";
            $this->load->helper(array('form'));
            $this->load->view('signup',$data);
        }

        public function verify(){
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'created_on' => date("F j Y")
            );
            $r =  $this->db->insert('users',$data);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $p = $this->db->insert('listing',array('user_id'=>$id));
            if($r){
                $data = array(
                        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                        'user_id' => $id,
                        'validated' => true
                        );
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect(URL.'users');
            }
        }

        public function check_username(){
            $result = $this->users_model->check_username($_POST['val']);
            $count = $result->result()[0]->count;
                if($count == 0)
                    echo 1;
                else
                    echo 0;
        }

        public function check_email(){
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what controller are you having trouble with? is it on the name controller and signup method?

Comment: the closing tag of php `?>` sometimes produces problem make sure you remove it

Comment: @tomexsans the control name is Signup and the file name is signup.php

Comment: can u paste ur controller code and the method to which ur calling in that particular controller.

Comment: @raheelshan so I should ommit all the closing tags from there.

Comment: Check php version, check error log, turn display_error on.

Comment: @ben I have turned display_error on and checked nothing happened.

Comment: @AmitHorakeri , I have posted my controller code.

Comment: @raheelshan - care to elaborate on why the closing php tag would cause problems?

Comment: @KCloud what's your local dev environment and what's your live environment? (os, php version)

Comment: @Ben , am using PHP5.4 at my local, and 5.2 at my server, secondly I haven't used any 5.4 code in my coding, and other controllers are running well, as i quoted.

Comment: remove the closing `?>` tag it would cause problems http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag for some if not for all

Comment: @tomexsans initially it didn't had closing ?> tags, I added that, thinking that might work.

Comment: @KCloud `$result->result()[0]` is php 5.4 but won't work in php 5.2. It's called array dereferencing (ref http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: this is hard to debug, how about on your server logs? how about turning on `CI's` log and try to log something on your `index` method

or try doing this `echo $this->load->view('signup',$data,TRUE);` if it works tell me.

Comment: had the same problem when autoloading database library with incorrect db settings. got blank screen, also with `display_error` on. you might check that...

Comment: @Ben , thanks that might be usefull, will implement it and review you all.

Comment: @Ben I have replace the code you identified as php5.4, but no result, still the same blank page

Comment: I got my errors in error log @Ben, thanks it was version problem, it solved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problems are:

You are developing localy on windows and your server isnt - The problem might be because windows isn`t case sensitive - make sure you specify the right paths (capitalized, lowercase etc.)

On your local server error reporting is turned off and on server isn`t - you might be getting some error but beeing error reporting ot prod server removed you can`t see it. The error might be because of differences of versions and etc.. . The solution is to check your log on the prod server or set error reporting to show errors for the script that you have problems with.

Hint: As @raheel shan saig, if there is going to be only php in your file never close the tag (?>). This cause many problems, one of them beeing - When you use this script the first response that it will return is the white space after the "?>" tag and this will cause sessions and cookies to malfunction.

Hope i was usefull